# Html.Grid DisplayFormat data annotation does not work

Tags: mvccontrib-grid

I am trying to bind my view model to the Html.Grid. I have set the DisplayFormat annotation to one of my property. However, the format is not applied when the grid is rendered.

Here's the code:
In view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,10:###,0}")]
public double AmountCurrency { get; set; }
```

On aspx:

```
    <%= Html.Grid<MyViewModel>(Model.MyViewModel)
            .Columns( column => {
             column.For(x => x.AmountCurrency);
...
```

When I format it in the aspx it works:

```
column.For(x => x.AmountCurrency).Format("{0,10:###,0}");
```

Not sure why it doesn't work with Data Annotation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Guys, any idea what is my mistake here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Docs](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&version=19) and [Jeremy Skinner's comment](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/23/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-3-gridmodels-and-gridrenderers/comment-page-1/#comment-20079), I think this only works with Auto-generated columns.

If auto-generated columns don't work, then a [custom grid renderer](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/23/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-3-gridmodels-and-gridrenderers) might be the way to go.

Comment: +1 Yes, it does work only with auto-generated columns. Thanks for the custom grid renderer link.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2  of MvcContrib its Grid ignored both DisplayFormat and DisplayName attributes. And it is fixed in version 3.0.51.0 - see this:
http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7064

I have checked this and it works properly now (even if the columns are not auto-generated).